# if and else condition not working on session variables?

Tags: php, session, if-statement

i need to solve this issue i have two different `session variables` and i want echo message and radio button name size values in if and else condition via `session variable`?

Problem is that when i select radio button it should be display `size values` instead of `accessories`?

**For Example I Want Like This**

If Input Values Like Any Number

```
echo "Accessories"; // It Should Be Display Accessories If
                       Any Kind Of Numbers Enter.
```

Else If Radio Select

```
echo size name // display size whatever choose 
                  from radio button.
```

**Here's my code:**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_REQUEST['test']))
{
$_SESSION['size1']=$_POST['size'];
$new_sizes=$_SESSION['size1'];
$_SESSION['cid1']=$_POST['cid'];

if(isset($_SESSION['cid1']))    
{
echo "Accessories";
}

else
{
echo $new_sizes;
}
}
?>

<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="cid">
<br>
<label for="Small">Small</label>
<input type="radio" name="size" id="Small" value="Small" />
<label for="Medium" >Medium</label>
<input type="radio" name="size" id="Medium" value="Medium"/>
<label for="Large">Large</label>
<input type="radio" name="size" id="Large" value="Large"/>
<label for="Xl">Xl</label>
<input type="radio" name="size" id="Xl" value="Xl"/>
<br>  
<input type="submit" name="test" value"Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: `cid1` will always be set because the input will always be posted, even if its value is "";

Comment: @lampwins what's the solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try

something like

```
if(is_numeric($_SESSION['cid1'])) 
{
  echo "Accessories";   
}
else
{
  echo $new_sizes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Re-Write code like this:

<?php
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
    session_start();
    if (empty($_POST) === false) {
        if (empty($_POST['size']) === false) {
    $_SESSION['size1']=$_POST['size'];
            echo $new_sizes = $_POST['size'];
        } else if (empty($_POST['cid']) === false) {
        $_SESSION['cid1']=$_POST['cid'];
            echo "Accessories";
        }
    }
    ?>
```